# flask restapi get query param not working for me

Tags: python, flask, get

I have the below `python` code which use `flask` and `request`:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/v1/api/check_current_weather_by_city?city=Tel-aviv')
def check_current_weather_by_city():
    city = request.args.get('city')
```

but city doesn't get the expected value of Tel-aviv, but throw me exception:

```
_lookup_req_object
        raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

I'm working with this service:
https://openweathermap.org/current

Comment: `@app.route('/v1/api/check_current_weather_by_city')`

Comment: Remove the `?city=Tel-aviv` part from the rule definition. That it's the request that may give that .And how to you call it ?

Comment: Per the documentation of the service, the call is: `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have mixed issues in your hands. First of all, your route should not contain the `?city=Tel-aviv`, just the "static" part of your URL.

Replace this line:

```
@app.route('/v1/api/check_current_weather_by_city?city=Tel-aviv')
```

By this line:

```
@app.route('/v1/api/check_current_weather_by_city')
```

Despite this issue, it shouldn't raise you the `RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.`. Be sure to initialize flask properly, the `app` was initialized in this file? You may need to have a line like this: `app = Flask(__name__)`

Is this a blueprint? If it is, be sure to initialize it too. Check the [official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/).

Comment: Tnx. I also used this: https://riptutorial.com/flask/example/26930/accessing-query-string